# Phonegap 3.3 app for Android behaves very different when debugging in Eclipse vs. release

Tags: android, eclipse, memory-management, cordova, notifications

Some background on my application: I am developing an app that will be used by a small user study group. They are to go through two separate short questionnaires throughout a day. Within a day I **schedule seven notifications** to fire. If a user clicks on a notification they are taking to complete one of the two survey types. **Each notification will be cancelled within 3 minutes of it triggering**. If a user does not access the notification within that time, then **the app records that a notification has been missed**. There is also bedtime function (user receives no notifications) and a delay notification function for notifications that are currently triggered.

I add local notifications with this plugin: 
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

So on to the weird issues... I have been debugging my PhoneGap application religiously for the past two weeks and everything seems to be working perfectly when I debug the application in Eclipse with my phone. A member of my research group says that he sees certain GLARING bugs in the application when he runs my release, but I have could not reproduce them while debugging in Eclipse. I figure he is using an old APK and doesn't know what he is talking about, as I had already fixed the issues he was mentioning...

Then I unplug my phone and carry it around with me for a day and all is well until the next morning when an alarm is scheduled to go off and wake me up. I hear nothing, so I continue sleeping. When I eventually wake up I see that I have a stack of 3 notifications in my status bar, all of which cancel at the same time about three minutes after I wake my phone up... I should mention that for the sake of debugging, I increased the number of surveys a day to 50, explaining the quick succession of notifications.

Now I've recently come to the conclusion that this is an issue with how Android conducts memory management-- Android will kill low priority tasks, such as the javascript timeout functions that I have running via a background-mode plugin

background mode plugin I use: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

It turns out that , for Android, this plugin only enables/disables a flag that tells Android not to kill the process... however for the sake of memory management, this flag is overridden and the js functions running in the background of my application are killed... this explains the previous strange behavior.

However, there a couple other odd things that only happen to my app when running it in release... If I delay a notification (cancels current notification and adds another one ten minutes from now), sometimes the login process screws up, requiring me to login twice at a minimum. Sometimes the login procedure just repeats itself over and over again, taking the user to the main menu then sending them back to the login screen. Other times I cannot log in at all... However, if I keep trying to log in, it will eventually give way and I can get in, but only after quite a few tries...

I have been through my code very thoroughly and there is no way that my code would result in this sort of behavior... What I am wondering is if this memory management issue mentioned above is contributing to these strange states of the application? Why does this not occur when I debug within Eclipse (This has never happened when debugging)?

I have no experience debugging issues with memory, but this is the only explanation as to why my code is acting so strangely...

I can post code, but I don't know how much use it will be... Really I just want to know if this sounds familiar to anyone who has experienced issues with Android managing its memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been in contact with PhoneGap Support and they have this to say,

"I talked to our lead Android developer on our team and he had this to say:

"Yeah, this guy is going to get garbage collected if he leaves his Cordova app running for a long period of time. We allow apps to run in the background for short periods by default since this is what people expect with the Android life cycle, but anything not on top of the stack is low priority, and you will need to implement a background service to do what he's wanting.

As far as running on Eclipse, anything with a debugger attached will be kept alive, because the debugger is a system process and has higher priority."

Al"